# When replacing the Variant Human race with a lineage, do you keep the skill proficiency gained through the Prodigy feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, skills, racial-traits, human

Each of the lineages from *Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft* has a feature called Ancestral Legacy, which states:

> If you replace a race with this lineage, you can keep the following elements of that race: any skill proficiencies you gained from it and any climbing, flying, or swimming speed you gained from it.

Suppose a Variant Human takes the Prodigy feat at 1st level. Prodigy states:

> You gain one skill proficiency of your choice, one tool proficiency of your choice, and fluency in one language of your choice.

Does the skill proficiency from Prodigy count as "gained from" your previous race for the purpose of retaining it when replacing your race with a lineage?

Comment: Related: [Do the new lineages in Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft work with Variant Human?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/185278)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No.

You quote:

> ... you can keep the following elements of that race: any skill proficiencies you gained from it and any climbing, flying, or swimming speed you gained from it.

Further, The rules for lineages state (emphasis mine):

> If you choose a lineage, you might have once been a member of another race, but you aren’t any longer. **You now possess only your lineage’s racial traits**.

This is quite clear in what *exactly* can carry over.

The [Variant Human](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/human#VariantHuman) rules allow us to pick a feat as a racial ability, but what we get from such a feat isn't itself a racial ability. Further, bonuses granted as part of a feat are just that: part of the feat.

Prodigy doesn't say "add one skill proficiency of your choice to your list of racial skill bonuses." We gain the skill proficiency from the *feat*, not by virtue of being Variant Human.