Can you keep the feat gained from Variant Human when changing to a Reborn lineage?
I have a question regarding the Reborn race. I've been playing a Variant Human Rogue who had recently died (killed by a Mummy Lord), and the DM has given me the option to return as a Reborn. But the Reborn says that I lose any features from my previous race, does that mean that I would lose the feat that the Variant Human starts with?

I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before.

Was your feat "Skilled", "Acrobat", "Skill Expert",  or anything else that gives you a skill as a part of the feat?

No
The text says that you lose any features from your previous race, which means that you lose any features from your previous race. The feat gained from Variant Human is a feature from your previous race.
However, the Ancestral Legacy trait says

If you replace a race with this lineage, you can keep the following elements of that race: any skill proficiencies you gained from it and any climbing, flying, or swimming speed you gained from it.

So you can, optionally, keep any skill proficiencies and climbing, flying and swimming speeds.

Related to this answer is my question here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/185284/62294
